# Powershell - How to send email to different group base on values in column

Tags: arrays, powershell, email

I have $pivot array which contains

```
Park    Date    Register    A   B   C
AA  9/28/2020   675 318.94  640.7   640.7
BB  9/28/2020   466 53.88   415.39  415.39
BB  9/28/2020   415 -80 241 241
BB  9/28/2020   417 33.14   334.15  334.15
BB  9/28/2020   492 871.33  1194.02 1194.02
BB  9/28/2020   985 1664.58 1976.38 1976.38
CC  9/28/2020   419 1246.47 1742.58 1742.58
CC  9/28/2020   400 2381.78 2681.5  2681.5
DD  9/28/2020   400 4526.26 4843.4  4843.4
DD  9/28/2020   410 5337.33 5670.11 5670.11
FF  9/28/2020   721 429.56  767.73  767.73
FF  9/28/2020   583 -73.92  234.48  234.48
FF  9/28/2020   803 -100    298.39  298.39
FF  9/28/2020   603 749.42  1057.83 1057.83
FF  9/28/2020   701 1485.16 1812.77 1812.77
```

I need to send records of park AA and BB to team1@something.com, CC and DD records to team2@something.com and FF records to team3@something.com. This does not have to be dynamic, I have a list of parks and emails associate with it. How can I achieve this? Thank you for your help.

---

Updated:

I got it to here, but receiving 5 duplicate emails because there is 5 parks. How can I update to only receive 1 email?

```
ForEach($park in $pivot)
    {
        if($park.Park -eq "AA" -or $park.Park -eq "BB")
        {
            # Convert results into html format
            $Html = $pivot | Where-Object { $_.Park -in "AA","BB" } | Sort-Object "Park", "Date", "Store", "Register" |
            ConvertTo-Html -Property "Park", "Date", "Store", "Register", "A", "B", "C"  -Head $style -Body "<h2>XBR - XCenter - Xstore Discrepancies Alert</h2>" -CssUri "http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css"  | 
            Out-String 
            $SMTPProperties.To = "team1@something.com"
        $SMTPProperties.Subject = $SMTPProperties.Subject + $MessageCount.'MessageCount'
        # Send the email
        Send-MailMessage @SMTPProperties -Body $Html -BodyAsHtml           
        Write-Host "Email has been sent to" $SMTPProperties.To
        }        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just need to change my code a little bit and it seems to work for me. If you have better solution, please drop in the comment section and I am new to PS so I would love to learn it from you. Thank you!

```
if($pivot.Park -eq "AA" -or $park.Park -eq "BB")
            {
                $parkdata = $pivot | Where-Object { $_.Park -in "AA","BB" } | Sort-Object "Park", "Date", "Store", "Register"
                $Html = $parkdata | ConvertTo-Html -Property "Park", "Date", "Store", "Register", "A", "B", "C"  -Head $style -Body "<h2>XBR - XCenter - Xstore Discrepancies Alert</h2>" -CssUri "http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css"  | 
                Out-String 
                $SMTPProperties.To = "team1@something.com"
                $SMTPProperties.Subject = $SMTPProperties.Subject + $MessageCount.'MessageCount'
                # Send the email
                Send-MailMessage @SMTPProperties -Body $Html -BodyAsHtml           
                Write-Host "Email has been sent to" $SMTPProperties.To
            }
```